# Extract lines from a file on unix

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a file on unix containing several lines with the word 'wonder'.
(There would be only one instance of wonder in each line that contains it)
I would like to extract the line containing the 'n'th occurrence of 'wonder'-and x lines before and after that.

Appreciate help with a script that would allow me the above.

Comment: When you say 'extract', do you mean 'remove', or 'locate'?

Answer (score 2):

Use a 2-pass approach:

```
awk -v n=3 -v x=5 '
BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
NR == FNR {
    if ( /wonder/ && (++c == n) ) {
        for (i=0; i<=x; i++) {
            tgts[FNR-i]
            tgts[FNR+i]
        }
    }
    next
}
FNR in tgts
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep -n -m 4 to print the line numbers of the first 4 matches, so grep -n -m 4 | tail -1 would give you the line number of the 4th match.

```
MATCH=4; LINES=5
span=$(($LINES*2+1))
line=`grep -n -m $MATCH wonder file | tail -1`
```

If you have the line number of the match, then you could print +/- N lines with head and tail...

```
end=$(($line+$LINES))
head -$end file |tail -$span
```

or you could use awk, count number of matches, and print lines after that match.  the harder part is rewinding to print N lines prior to that.  You could buffer lines, but that is harder.

*(I usually use perl for stuff like this.)*

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`, you can also achieve this with a one-liner by using the `-C` flag

```
grep -m N -C x wonder file | tail -n 2*x+1
```

Where you have to replace `2*x+1` with the corresponding number.